# Prevent linebreak in siunitx' numrange

Tags: siunitx

How can i forbid linebreaks in the `\numrange{}{}`command of `siunitx`?

The example below is done with spectroscopy module from chemmacros, but that doesn't matter here since it the `\val{}`command uses the `\numrange{}{}` command. Typing

```
\sisetup{range-phrase = \nolinebreak--\nolinebreak}
```

doesn't work

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{range-phrase = --}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{
    modules={spectroscopy},
    greek=chemgreek,
    spectroscopy/format = \bfseries,
    spectroscopy/list = true,
    spectroscopy/coupling-pos = sub,
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{experimental}
\vspace{-\baselineskip}\data{\NMR*{1,H} (ac\_prakt.794.1)} (\SI{400}{\mega\hertz}, \SI{298}{K}, \ch{CDCl3}, $\delta$/ppm):
    \val{7.74--7.83}~(m,~\#{12},~\pos{4}),
    \val{7.36--7.50}~(m,~\#{24},~\pos{2,3}),
    \val{7.14--7.32}~(m,~\#{24},~\pos{2,3}).
\end{experimental}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
\sisetup{range-phrase = \mbox{--}}
```

so the dash will not be considered for a line break. A `\nolinebreak` is ineffective, because already `-` is a feasible break point.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that works, sorry for the stupid question. I actually thought `\mbox{}`cannot work since then it makes `7.74\mbox{--}7.83` so there can still be a break before and after the mbox. So, why does mbox work?

Comment: @Wulfram It hides the dash one level of boxing below, so it can't be considered as a break point. There is no break point on either side of `\mbox`.